# Psycopg missing module in Django

Tags: python, django, pip, psycopg2, psycopg

I have pip installed psycopg2, but when I try to runserver or syncdb in my Django project, it raises an error saying there is "**no module named _psycopg**".

EDIT: the "syncdb" command now raises:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError django.contrib.admin: No module named _psycopg

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by performing a clean reinstall of django. There was apparently some dependecies missing that the recursive pip install did not seem to be able to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've enabled `psycopg2` and not `psycopg` in the `settings.py` file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
```

And not:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg',
```

Comment: I use dj_database but yeah it uses psycopg2 in its schemes:
SCHEMES = {
    'postgres': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'postgresql': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'postgis': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'mysql': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'mysql2': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'sqlite': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
}